# Is there a way to put python (django) variables into jquery onmouseover popup?

Tags: jquery, django, python-2.7, onmouseover

I'm trying to create popups for my website when someone scrolls over an image. The problem is that I am trying to display different information about people when you scroll over their avatar, and I use a for loop to display all the people.  When I use the following code, the correct avatar for each person is displayed, however the popup information is always the same for each person, and not the information specific to that person.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var moveLeft = 20;
  var moveDown = 10;

  $('a#trigger').hover(function(e) {
    $('div.pop-up').show();
      //.css('top', e.pageY + moveDown)
      //.css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft)
      //.appendTo('body');
  }, function() {
    $('div.pop-up').hide();
  });

  $('a#trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
    $("div.pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
  });

});
</script>

{% for person in people %}
<div id="container">
    <a href="#" id="trigger"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ person.avatar }}" /></a>
    <div class="pop-up">
        <h3>{{ person.name }}</h3>
        <p>{{ person.other_info }}</p>
    </div>
</div>

#Style Sheet
div.pop-up {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

So each person in the loop will have their avatar displayed, but when I scroll over their avatar, the information for the last person in the list is displayed.  Anyone know what to do to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull, use class instead of IDs on your elements and ensure you select only the sibling popup:

```
$(function() {
    var moveLeft = 20;
    var moveDown = 10;

    $('a.trigger').hover(function(e) {
      $(this).next('.pop-up').show();
        //.css('top', e.pageY + moveDown)
        //.css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft)
        //.appendTo('body');
    }, function() {
      $(this).next('.pop-up').hide();
    });

    $('a.trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
      $(this).next('.pop-up')
        .css('top', e.pageY + moveDown)
        .css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    });
});
```

```
{% for person in people %}
<div class="person-container">
  <a href="#" class="trigger"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ person.avatar }}" /></a>
  <div class="pop-up">
      <h3>{{ person.name }}</h3>
      <p>{{ person.other_info }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```